# Connecting to internet using Wi-fi portable hotspot or bluetooth? which one is more battery saving?

Tags: bluetooth, battery-life, wifi-hotspot

I have EDGE internet connection in my Samsung Europa I5500L (Froyo 2.2). I can connect to the Internet from my laptop using both **bluetooth** or **making a wifi hotspot** from the device using that EDGE connection.

`{internet}-----[phone]-----{wifi/bluetooth}-----[laptop]`

My question is which one will be more battery saving for both my laptop and mobile?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It depends on your phone and your laptop.  You should just try it and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally Bluetooth uses less power. On my HTC Desire, I use Bluetooth because it lasts longer and consumes much less power compared to Wi-Fi hotspot when connection is idle.